# Deployment of runbook module failed, because it reached terminal provisioning state 'Failed'

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-automation, azure-bicep, azure-runbook

I want to create some automation runbooks with PowerShell on Azure using bicep. For that I need some custom modules listed below.

```
var modules = [
    'Microsoft.Graph.Authentication'
    'Microsoft.Graph.Groups'
    'Microsoft.Graph.Mail'
    'Microsoft.Graph.Planner'
    'Microsoft.Graph.Teams'
    'Microsoft.Graph.Users'
    'Microsoft.Graph.Users.Actions'
]
```

Here is how I create the modules:

```
resource automationResource 'Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts@2022-08-08' = {
    // Some other properties

    resource moduleResources 'modules' = [for module in modules: {
        name: module
        properties: {
            contentLink: {
                uri: 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/'
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

When I deploy this to Azure I got next error for all modules:

```json
{
    "status": "Failed",
    "error": {
        "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
        "target": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/xxx/modules/Microsoft.Graph.Teams",
        "message": "The resource write operation failed to complete successfully, because it reached terminal provisioning state 'Failed'."
    }
}
```

Why won't the modules not be added to the automation account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things here:

1. You need the full url of the package: name + version
2. If a package has some dependencies, dependencies need to be imported first.

Here, all the packages depends on the `Microsoft.Graph.Authentication` package.

The easiest way to achieve that is to deploy the modules sequentially but it will be quite slow:

```
var modules = [
  {
    name: 'Microsoft.Graph.Authentication'
    version: '2.0.0-preview8'
  }
  {
    name: 'Microsoft.Graph.Groups'
    version: '2.0.0-preview8'
  }
  {
    name: 'Microsoft.Graph.Mail'
    version: '2.0.0-preview8'
  }
  {
    name: 'Microsoft.Graph.Planner'
    version: '2.0.0-preview8'
  }
  {
    name: 'Microsoft.Graph.Teams'
    version: '2.0.0-preview8'
  }
  {
    name: 'Microsoft.Graph.Users'
    version: '2.0.0-preview8'
  }
  {
    name: 'Microsoft.Graph.Users.Actions'
    version: '2.0.0-preview8'
  }
]

resource automationAccount 'Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts@2022-08-08' existing = {
  name: automationAccountName
}

@batchSize(1)
resource automationAccountModules 'Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/modules@2022-08-08' = [for module in modules: {
  parent: automationAccount
  name: module.name
  properties: {
    contentLink: {
      uri: toLower('https://devopsgallerystorage.blob.core.windows.net:443/packages/${module.name}.${module.version}.nupkg')
    }
  }
}]
```

or you could import the `Microsoft.Graph.Authentication` beofre importing other modules:

```
var modules = [
  {
    name: 'Microsoft.Graph.Authentication'
    version: '2.0.0-preview8'
  }
  {
    name: 'Microsoft.Graph.Groups'
    version: '2.0.0-preview8'
  }
  {
    name: 'Microsoft.Graph.Mail'
    version: '2.0.0-preview8'
  }
  {
    name: 'Microsoft.Graph.Planner'
    version: '2.0.0-preview8'
  }
  {
    name: 'Microsoft.Graph.Teams'
    version: '2.0.0-preview8'
  }
  {
    name: 'Microsoft.Graph.Users'
    version: '2.0.0-preview8'
  }
  {
    name: 'Microsoft.Graph.Users.Actions'
    version: '2.0.0-preview8'
  }
]

resource automationAccount 'Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts@2022-08-08' existing = {
  name: automationAccountName
}

var authPackage = first(modules)
resource authModule 'Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/modules@2022-08-08' = {
  parent: automationAccount
  name: authPackage.name
  properties: {
    contentLink: {
      uri: toLower('https://devopsgallerystorage.blob.core.windows.net:443/packages/${authPackage.name}.${authPackage.version}.nupkg')
    }
  }
}

var otherPackages = skip(modules, 1)
resource automationAccountModules 'Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/modules@2022-08-08' = [for module in otherPackages: {
  dependsOn: [ authModule ]
  parent: automationAccount
  name: module.name
  properties: {
    contentLink: {
      uri: toLower('https://devopsgallerystorage.blob.core.windows.net:443/packages/${module.name}.${module.version}.nupkg')
    }
  }
}]
```